# I am loading image from local from ios device but its not desplaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I want to load image from local in ios,

I added this code in my file,

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/Small-mario.png", NSHomeDirectory()];
    NSLog(@"path %@", path);
displayImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:path];
```

the path iget is,

> /Users/WTS-New/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F43C26D2-DCFF-4764-AAF0-F6CC7BCDCF5D/data/Containers/Data/Application/06FE9A96-7705-4FB7-B291-4716CC6679C3/Documents/Small-mario.png

But image is not displaying in imageview.

Comment: imageNamed wont work, use `NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path` and then `UIImage imageWithData:`

Comment: the image "Small-mario.png" is in your app bundle?

Comment: he image "Small-mario.png" is in my gallery. @ddb

Comment: what do you mean by gallery ?

Comment: My iphone gallery. @KetanParmar

Comment: Yes photo library. @KetanParmar

Comment: then you should use `UIImagePickerController` to pick the image!!!1

Answer (score 0):

in your app you can't access images that are not in your app bundle

you have two choices:

1. make use import it using UIImagePickerController
2. put the image you need in your app bundle

Comment: Can you give example of it? @ddb

Comment: about what? please, follow the links, they will guide you to StackOverflow documentation ;)

Comment: can you describe how to store it in app bundle? @ddb

Comment: you have to take the image file and put it in "image assets" of your Xcode project, you can see how to do it [at this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingImageSets.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can pick image like,

```
 UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; // this is your picked image

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And make sure that you are confirming `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

Comment: can you describe how to store it in app bundle? @Ketan Parmar

Comment: you can store it in document directory. You can store anything in app bundle programmatically. You can drag and drop image in app bundle in xcode. You don't have write permission for app bundle so you can't write programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

plz use this

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/Small-mario.png", NSHomeDirectory()];
    NSLog(@"path %@", path);
displayImg.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

or you can use

```
 NSURL *destinationURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

displayImg.image =[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:destinationURL]]
```

Comment: I got the image path like, "/Users/WTS-New/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F43C26D2-DCFF-4764-AAF0-F6CC7BCDCF5D/data/Containers/Data/Application/8E49D340-7CAC-4031-85BF-9E5C26A1E37A/Documents/Small-mario.png", But image not displaying in displayImg.image. @balkaran singh